# WF4: Transition check order

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

In a state machine I have a state which has an entry activity and that activity has an out parameter which contains the information about the next state.

This info is then checked in the transition conditions.

One of the pitfalls is that you may overlook a transition. I wanted to create a default transition that runs into a logging activity and returns the state machine into a stable condition without getting stuck in that state because no transition condition evaluates to true.

However I can't just have a conditionless transition because there appears to be no way to order the checks like one would do in a code `switch` statement.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you set your Out parameter to a default state e.g. "NoTransition", at the start of your activity.  Then if the Out parameter is not set to a valid transition during the activity the "NoTransition" state is output and acts as the default and can be picked up by the transition conditions

Comment: But it is possible that the Out parameter will get some value in the transition, just not one that is matched by any condition. But the "NoTransition" will be overwritten as well.